# window methods in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

Is it safe to use `window.open()` in Lightning Components? This lightning component is going to be used in a Lightning Community.

I cannot use `force:navigateToURL` as it is giving some other issues.

Comment: what issues are related to 'force:navigateToURL' ? can you further expand on your use case? are you opening external links, salesforce records within the communtiy, salesforcec LEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to access any function [permitted by Locker Service](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV). `window.open` is permitted by Locker Service and should work just fine. I recommend you bookmark the above link so you can check which operations are permitted when in doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdxfox. That is really a useful resource.